# Clases, atributos, objetos y diccionarios en python

Tags: python, poo

tengo una duda con el siguiente código:

```
class Prueba():
    atributo = {}

p = Prueba()
p.atributo['a'] = 1

z = Prueba()
z.atributo
{'a':1}
```

¿Como es posible que creando un objeto nuevo, éste tenga el diccionario que le fue asignado al objeto anterior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debes diferenciar lo que se conoce como "atributos de clase" y "atributos de una instancia".

Cuando usas el primer código que pusiste, estas modificando ese atributo de clase y, todas las instancias que generes de esa clase tendrán las modificaciones que le hayas ido aplicando. En el caso de que hagas algo como esto:

```
class Prueba():
    def __init__(self):
        self.atributo = {}

p = Prueba()
p.atributo['a'] = 1
print p.atributo

z = Prueba()
z.atributo
print z.atributo
```

estarás modificando atributo en cada una de las instancias que generes. Obteniendo lo que querías:

```
{'a': 1}
{}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Las [variables de clase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_de_clase) y las [variables de instancia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_de_instancia) tienen un comportamiento estraño en python, si asigno valores nuevos a las variables de clase estos se limitan al ambito de la instancia a pesar de ser variables de clase pero si tengo un diccionario, lista o tulpa como variable de clase y en vez de asignarle un diccionario, lista o tulpa nuevos, modifico los que ya tienen estos datos si estan compartidos entre las diferentes instancias de la clase.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay una declaración de la clase, lo que hago es inicializar el atributo.
Esta información la he sacado de [esta](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/2/classes.html) página

```
class Prueba:
    def __init__(self):
        self.atributo = {}

p = Prueba()
p.atributo['a'] = 1
z = Prueba ()
print p.atributo['a']
print z.atributo['a']
```

Esto medio como resultado

> ```
> 1                                                                                                                                                                   
> Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                  
>   File "main.py", line 16, in <module>                                                                                                                              
>     print z.atributo['a']
> ```

Ejecutando el código en está [página](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php), que sirve para ejecutar código Python Online, y [aquí](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#) otro link para poder analizar el código de Python

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Entiendo como conseguir las variables de instancia muchas pero me he leido la documentación que enlazas y no consigo encontrar donde se describe el comportamiento de las variables de clase en python.  ¿Porque solo comparte en algunos casos, como cuando editas el diccionario de la variable de clase y no se comparte si cambias el valor de una cadena o un entero o si asignas un diccionario nuevo?